# Part in KOMA adds enddots to numbers?

Tags: numbering, koma-script

All is (typographically) fine with this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{chapter}
  \chapter{chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as soon as I add `\part` to it the numbers are getting enddots:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{part}
  \chapter{chapter}
  \chapter{chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get rid of the enddots one needs `numbers=noenddot`:

```
\documentclass[
numbers=noenddot
]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{part}
  \chapter{chapter}
  \chapter{chapter}
\end{document}
```

What is the reason for putting dots to the numbers as soon as one has `\part` in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the KOMA script documentation (section '3.16. Structuring of Documents', page 95):

> KOMA-Script decides, whether or not to set the period at the end of
>   the numbers. The numbers consists in Arabic digits only, the period
>   will be omitted. If there are alphabetic characters or roman numbers
>   the period will always be set.

In your example, parts are numbered with roman numbers which is why a period is used if you include a part.

Comment: strange behaviour but I will accept it.

Comment: @LukasCB I seem to remember this is some kind of 'rule' in German texts, but I only found http://golatex.de/richtige-kapitelnummerierung-nach-duden-t14480.html and nothing official (my Rechtschreib-Duden didn't mention this, but I don't have a Duden style guide or DIN ... whatever ... at hand to check with them).